# IIS manager rewrite all URLS after mysite.com/

Tags: url, iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-manager

I'm trying to rewrite all the urls for my website.
For example, if the user types in mysite.com/index.aspx 
it'll change the url in the top to www.mysite.com/index.aspx

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Enforce canonical hostname" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.mysite\.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mysite.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Where would I put this piece of code? I was using IIS Manager for most of my rewrites/redirects.

Comment: The rewrite rules are stored either in the ApplicationHost.config file or in Web.config files.

Open a Web.config file located in %SystemDrive%\inetput\wwwroot\